# Having difficulty extracting test titles and test results from a list of text

Tags: python, algorithm

I've got a list of lines of text that are comprised of alternating section-headers and section-content. I want to parse it line by line, and identify the sections and their associated content (to eventually throw together into a dictionary).

The trouble I am having is in figuring out how to parse the lines into pairs based only on iterating through the list and looking for the headers. Everytime I try I get very close, but somehow my sections end up misaligned.

I think my algorithm should be as follows:

(0) Assume no header has been identified at the beginning of the search; hence, any content seen will be ignored until a section header is encountered.

(1) When "in" a section (i.e. a section header has been encountered), accumulate all following section content and append it together, until such a time as a new section header is seen.

(2) Upon encountering the new section header, any following lines should be considered as part of the new section.

(3) Some sections may only have a header, and hence have blank content. Others may span a single or multiple lines.

In other words, given this:

```
garbage
Section-A-Header
section A content line 1
section A content line 2
section A content line 3
Section-B-Header
section B content line 1
section B content line 2
Section-C-Header
Section-D-Header
section D content line 1
section D content line 2
section D content line 3
```

...I would like to be able to construct:

```
{Section-A-Header: section A content line 1 + section A content line 2 + section A content line 3}
{Section-B-Header: section B content line 1 + section B content line 2}
{Section-C-Header: None}
{Section-D-Header: section D content line 1 + section D content line 2 + section D content line 3}
```

Could anyone help me figure out a solid implementation?

**UPDATE**
Sample data of the real code I am dealing with is located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71723787/having-difficulty-extracting-test-titles-and-test-results-from-a-list-of-text/71727812#71727812).

Comment: 1. How do you identify a header? 2. What have you tried? Add that to the question as well. 3. What exact issue are you facing?

Comment: While testing data *is* helpful, would you mind providing some *real* sample data please? (This could completely change the approach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is the exact issue you are facing with this.

Here is a pseudocode for you to take inspiration from

```
file = open("sections.txt", 'r')

last_header=''
output = {}
for line in file.readlines():
    if is_section_header(line):
        last_header = line
        output[line] = ""
    else:
        existing_data = output[last_header]
        output[last_header] = existing_data + line

print(output)


def is_section_header(line):
    #some logic to identify header
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be my approach:

```
result = dict()

with open('foo.txt') as foo:
    section = None
    for line in map(str.strip, foo):
        # identify start of section
        if line.startswith('Section-'):
            section = line
            result[section] = None
        else:
            if section:
                if result[section]:
                    result[section].append(line)
                else:
                    result[section] = [line]
```

**Result:**

```
{
  "Section-A-Header": [
    "section A content line 1",
    "section A content line 2",
    "section A content line 3"
  ],
  "Section-B-Header": [
    "section B content line 1",
    "section B content line 2"
  ],
  "Section-C-Header": None,
  "Section-D-Header": [
    "section D content line 1",
    "section D content line 2",
    "section D content line 3"
  ]
}
```

**Note:**

Written like this only because OP wants None for empty sections

Answer (score 0):

Some people wanted to see a sample of the actual data I am dealing with (which I was trying to avoid because it's quite a bit more complex than the sample data I gave above). This data is output from Pytest during a test run as it gets sent to the console, so it has ANSI encoding embedded in most lines of the text. I didn't include this before, because my difficulty was not in parsing the text, but in creating the overall algorithm that looks at the output line by line.

This is all part of a [Pytest plugin](https://github.com/jeffwright13/pytest-fold) I am developing that offers an auto-launching text user interface to hopefully make dealing with the verbose output of Pytest a little easier to analyze.

```
======================================================================================== FAILURES ========================================================================================
[31m[1m______________________________________________________________________________________ test_b_fail _______________________________________________________________________________________[0m

    [94mdef[39;49;00m [92mtest_b_fail[39;49;00m():
>       [94massert[39;49;00m [94m0[39;49;00m
[1m[31mE       assert 0[0m

[1m[31mtests/test_pytest_fold_1.py[0m:26: AssertionError
[31m[1m___________________________________________________________________________ test_g_eval_parameterized[6*9-42] ____________________________________________________________________________[0m

test_input = '6*9', expected = 42

    [37m@pytest[39;49;00m.mark.parametrize([33m"[39;49;00m[33mtest_input, expected[39;49;00m[33m"[39;49;00m, [([33m"[39;49;00m[33m3+5[39;49;00m[33m"[39;49;00m, [94m8[39;49;00m), ([33m"[39;49;00m[33m2+4[39;49;00m[33m"[39;49;00m, [94m6[39;49;00m), ([33m"[39;49;00m[33m6*9[39;49;00m[33m"[39;49;00m, [94m42[39;49;00m)])
    [94mdef[39;49;00m [92mtest_g_eval_parameterized[39;49;00m(test_input, expected):
>       [94massert[39;49;00m [96meval[39;49;00m(test_input) == expected
[1m[31mE       AssertionError: assert 54 == 42[0m
[1m[31mE        +  where 54 = eval('6*9')[0m

[1m[31mtests/test_pytest_fold_1.py[0m:48: AssertionError
```

The code I ended up having success with is based on Phenomenal One's answer. My regex definition is:

`r"\x1b\[31m\x1b\[1m__+\W(\S+)\W__+\x1b\[0m"`

...and the processing code is:

```
def _get_tracebacks(self, section_name: str, regex: str) -> dict:

    last_header = ""
    output = {}

    lines = re.split("\n", self.Sections[section_name].content)
    for line in lines:
        result = re.search(regex, line)
        if result:
            last_header = result.groups()[0]
            output[last_header] = ""
        else:
            if not last_header:
                continue
            existing_data = output[last_header]
            output[last_header] = existing_data + "\n" + line

    return output
```

Thanks to all who participated in this discussion!